# How can I add a start and end screen to my PyGame code?

Tags: python, pygame

I am not sure how to make a start or an end screen. I am still learning pygame. How can I add this to my game?

My full code is too long to put it here:

[script](https://pastebin.com/TpMRaM7Y)

I have a player health, here is my pseudocode:

```
if the player health reaches -1:
    it should load a end screen.
if playerman.health > -1:
    then load the end screen with some restart buttons!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use if and else:

edit

```
import time
page = 'startscreen'
while True:
  if page == 'startscreen':
      # display startscreen image
      if startbutton is clicked:
           page = 'game'
  elif page == 'game':
      #game code here

      if playerhealth <= -1:
          page = 'endscreen'
  elif page == 'endscreen':
      endscreen = pygame.Surface((screenwidth, screenheight))
      display.blit(endscreen, (0, 0))
      pygame.display.flip()
      time.sleep(1)
      break
      # blit an endscreen as a surface on your display, wait 1 second and stop the game
```

Comment: does this solve your problem?

Comment: here is the code from one of my games that use multiple menus https://pastebin.com/GRP8QSUM

Comment: wait do I put my entire code where you said #game code here? like everything that I have in my code?

Comment: this is what I have done I created a def function for the [endscreen](https://gyazo.com/19c6991a68822c709da372f84721a6d4)  and in my main loop I said if my [playerhealth < -1](https://gyazo.com/64e1c111fb8c2286c0709a0fa07d67fa) then it should blit the end screen I am confused on why it isnt workinggg

Comment: [start menu image](https://gyazo.com/0024ec35eb470c89ea4ac5acf55a0a0f) I have made a start menu I just need help if I click the start game menu should load my game

Comment: @Habib Ismail Your code should contain the following ```def maingameloop``` and ```def main_menu```. Under maingameloop put your entire game code for running your game. under main_menu create another gameloop with a ```while true``` statement and whatever you wish it to contain.

Comment: [script[(https://pastebin.com/dr25Q48P) could you see if I am doing it right I main a function called `def main_loop` then I put my entire code inside it except the start game window then at the very bottom I created a new `runninggame game event then called the main_loop  but I am getting an error `module 'pygame' has no attribute 'Quit'` I also dont know if I am doing it right

Comment: is this edited version better

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to put your main code inside a function. Create another function that holds a main menu screen next. Call the main menu screen when you start your game and make sure to include a button on it that calls the main game function.

I'm giving you my button class that I use below.

```
class Button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):

        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (
                self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))
```

Next create a main menu as follows.

```
    def main_menu():
        setDefaults()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Main Menu")
        run = True
        bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
        green = (0, 200, 0)
        screen.fill((163, 163, 194))
```

Set defaults is a function that converts all your values to your original ones. after this basic main menu make sure to add a button using my button class that I gave you earlier and link that to your main function or do this.

```
    while run:
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
                run = False

            if 400 + 100 > mouse[0] > 400 and 275 + 50 > mouse[1] > 275:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, bright_green, (400, 275, 100, 50))

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    main()
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (400, 275, 100, 50))
```

Also make sure to call the main menu when your health drops below 0(or any other condition).
Hope this helps.

Edits
To put your entire code inside a function, do this.

```
def main_loop():
    global dependencies for edits
    while running:
        ....your code...
```

Edits2

Given below is my main menu, please change the variables as required. Also make sure to replace `main()` with your `maingameloop` function

```
def main_menu():
    setDefaults()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Main Menu")
    run = True
    bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
    green = (0, 200, 0)
    screen.fill((163, 163, 194))
    # pygame.mixer.music.load('background_music_wav.wav')
    # pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    while run:

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
                run = False

            if 400 + 100 > mouse[0] > 400 and 275 + 50 > mouse[1] > 275:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, bright_green, (400, 275, 100, 50))

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    main()
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (400, 275, 100, 50)) 

            screen.blit(font_large.render("Game-Name", True, (255, 255, 255)), (325, 50)) 
            screen.blit(font.render("Play", True, (0, 0, 0)), (417, 285)) 


        pygame.display.flip() 
        clock.tick(FPS)       

main_menu()
```

Comment: @PyGamer Controlling your game code using functions and classes is a better method than controlling it using if else conditions. This offers more flexibility to your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: how can I put my main code in a function I am really confused

Comment: @Habib Ismail You are currently using a while loop to execute your main game loop right? So instead to just putting a while loop directly put your entire game loop inside a function and global any dependencies that you need to. I'm adding some more imfo to my answer so please take a look there

Comment: [image](https://i.gyazo.com/909c842b2bc98f67787bc883ca19a571.png) so I could just remove the runninggame  = False and instead of while runninggame I can change that to def main_loop():?

Comment: @Habib Ismail You dont need to change anything. Just put your entire game code under a function. Create another function which contains your main menu(create this also like a game loop). Call your main_menu and have a button on it which when clicked calls the maingameloop

Comment: [script](https://pastebin.com/dr25Q48P) could you see if I am doing it right I made a function called `def main_loop` then I put my entire code inside it except the `start game window `then at the very bottom I created a new `runninggame game event then called the main_loop ` but I am getting an error` module 'pygame' has no attribute 'Quit'` I also dont know if I am doing it right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215613/discussion-between-habib-ismail-and-rishi).

Comment: I tried to do what you did but my screen just appears as black

Comment: @HabibIsmail Please follow up in other questions in chat